# How to use Cons in Scala when implementing a linked list?

Tags: scala, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, cons

I have been trying to implement a linkedList in scala for a university course. So far I have implemented the **Empty** and the Constructor **Cons** and a few more methods. Right now I try to implement the **filter** function and since I was not progressing I had a look at the solutions our professor gave us. This is how he implements *filtering* on a LinkedList:

```
 override def filter(filterFunc: Int => Boolean): IntList = this match {
    case Empty => Empty
    case Cons(head, tail) if filterFunc(head) => Cons(head, tail.filter(filterFunc))
    case Cons(_, tail) => tail.filter(filterFunc)
  }
```

My question is what does `case Cons(_, tail) => tail.filter(filterFunc)` do exactly? I understand that the filter function is applied recursively on the tail but I dont understand how it gets appended to the list which should be returned at the end. I hope my question makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: `case Cons(_, tail)` means match any **Cons** and ignore its head. That makes sense, since we do not need this head since it didn't matched the predicate _(that was covered by the previous case statement)_. - Then you simply call filter on the tail and return that. It gets appended to the list that is being constructed, because the way recursion works. For exmaple, if the previous call fall under the second case, then the filtered tail will be passed to `Cons(head, tail.filter(filterFunc))` as the result of `tail.filter(...)`. It may help to execute the algorithm by hand using paper and pecil.

Comment: Try to write down every step on paper one by one. Each step replacing the call to filter withe the result from the match. This is called the substitution model.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should to understand - `Cons(head, tail)` - it's just a constructor of new List. 
Second thing - construction:

```
this match {
    case Empty => Empty
    case Cons(head, tail) if filterFunc(head) => Cons(head, tail.filter(filterFunc))
    case Cons(_, tail) => tail.filter(filterFunc)
  }
```

goes from up to down, and trying to match current list with patterns: `Empty`, `Cons(head, tail) if filterFunc(head)` or `case Cons(_, tail)`. If list is not empty and head passes predicate `filterFunc` it constructs new list with same head and call filter function on the tail, if you will do so, you will get new list from every call filter function. 
In line `case Cons(_, tail) => tail.filter(filterFunc)` it doesn't append result of filter function on tail, it's just return new list without *this head* and with filtered tail. If it was a recursive call from another place, then in this call new list will be constructed as a new object with some head and a result of call as tail.
Try read more about recursive data structures.